# Poetry: always have to install setuptools manually in CI

Tags: pip, setuptools, circleci, python-packaging, python-poetry

Im building my Circle CI flow with Poetry. Everything works well, except the thing that i should install setuptools always manually. It looks like this:

```
steps:
  - checkout

  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - pip-{{ checksum "poetry.lock" }}-{{ .Environment.CACHE_VERSION }}
  - run:
      name: install dependencies
      command: |
        poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
        poetry config virtualenvs.path /project
        poetry run pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
        poetry install
        poetry show -v


steps:

  - run:
      name: pytest
      command: |
        poetry run pip install setuptools
        poetry run pytest -sv tests/unittests
```

If im removing manual installation of `setuptools`, installing of some packages are failing with the same traceback. Example:

```
Installing googleads (29.0.0): Failed



EnvCommandError

  Command ['/home/circleci/project/.venv/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', '/home/circleci/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/05/59/83/1fa9c7bc74df8656d6fa40f159fa169c10a9a110501f2ec8260c8cd3e1/googleads-29.0.0.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing /home/circleci/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/05/59/83/1fa9c7bc74df8656d6fa40f159fa169c10a9a110501f2ec8260c8cd3e1/googleads-29.0.0.tar.gz
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /home/circleci/project/.venv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-e9n99b4s/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-e9n99b4s/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-8t_uwvq3
           cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-e9n99b4s/
      Complete output (3 lines):
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
      ----------------------------------------
  WARNING: Discarding file:///home/circleci/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/05/59/83/1fa9c7bc74df8656d6fa40f159fa169c10a9a110501f2ec8260c8cd3e1/googleads-29.0.0.tar.gz. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the '/home/circleci/project/.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  

  at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/utils/env.py:1183 in _run
      1179│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1180│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1181│                 )
      1182│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1183│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1184│ 
      1185│         return decode(output)
      1186│ 
      1187│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):
```

Tests are also failing if manual installation of setuptools gonna be removed, if i will not install setuptools manually on the test step. All tests are also failing with the same trace:

```
collection failure
ImportError while importing test module '/home/circleci/project/tests/unittests/hsplib/test_spark.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/unittests/hsplib/test_spark.py:9: in <module>
    from tests.unittests.testlib.asserts import assert_df_equal_2
tests/unittests/testlib/asserts.py:5: in <module>
    import chispa
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chispa/__init__.py:28: in <module>
    from .dataframe_comparer import DataFramesNotEqualError, assert_df_equality, assert_approx_df_equality
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chispa/dataframe_comparer.py:1: in <module>
    from chispa.prettytable import PrettyTable
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/chispa/prettytable.py:44: in <module>
    import pkg_resources
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

I want to get rid from this manual setuptools installation, but i cant understand whats wrong with it. It feels like a code smell. What i tryed:

- Adding `setuptools` as one of the dependencies in `pyproject.toml` file - no effect
- Adding `setuptools` to `build-system` requires - also no effect.
- Adding `virtualenvs.options.no-setuptools = false` to poetry config. It should be by default, but i tryed to setup it manually. No effect.

The only issue, that looks like a similar one that i found is this one:
https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4242

But there is still no answer there what to do.
My `poetry` version 1.3.2
`pip` version 22.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your project depends on some libraries that are poorly packaged. You should raise up the issue towards their maintainers on their issue trackers:

- https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/issues
- https://github.com/MrPowers/chispa/issues